# Entity Framework, trigger mechanism for before update values

Tags: entity-framework-4.1

Is there anyway in EF to have before update values of object?

e.g. When entity object let's say User is saved, i would like to know for logging purpose before update User object values.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4):

If you work with `ObjectContext` (edmx) you can subscribe to the [`SavingChanges`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.savingchanges.aspx) event.

```cs
context.SavingChanges += context_SavingChanges;
```

This gives access to the original and current values when `SaveChanges()` is executed:

```cs
private void context_SavingChanges (object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ObjectContext context = sender as ObjectContext;
    if (context != null)
    {
        foreach (ObjectStateEntry entry in context.ObjectStateManager
                                 .GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Modified))
        {
            // TODO: do some logging with these values.
            entry.OriginalValues;
            entry.CurrentValues;
        }
    }
}
```

If you work with DbContext you can get to the event by

```cs
((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext.SavingChanges
```

Comment: Happened to stumble upon this answer. Made a late edit to make it more applicable.

Comment: I wrote a library that offers trigger events. Hope it helps someone! https://github.com/NickStrupat/EntityFramework.Triggers