# ObjectContext's SavingChanges: find out which columns have changed?

Tags: entity-framework-4, save, objectcontext, auditing, timestamping

I'm handling ObjectContext's SavingChanges event to timestamp entries. The requirement is that, if only ColumnA has changed, I *don't* timestamp the entry when it changes.

Is there a way that I can find out which columns have changed (are changing) during this event?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you, this will loop through any Added/Modified entries, and if there is more than 1 modified property, and it's not "ColumnA" it you can modify the timestamp:

```cs
public int SaveChanges()
{
     foreach( ObjectStateEntry entry in ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries( EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified ) )
     {
         var properties = entry.GetModifiedProperties();

          if (!(properties.Count() == 1 && properties.First() == "ColumnA"))
          {
              //modify timestamp here
          }
     }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Correct, except that the OP asks about the SavingChanges event. The difference is minor: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11250496/861716

Comment: Ah you're right, apologies!  It will still work, just needs to be placed in the event handler as your post showed