# Cancelling and discard changes in Entity Framework and WPF

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, architecture, mvvm

I am developing a system where the user have forms to fill and this info is stored in a database. In one of the screens I have the following flow:

- Inside a project he can add multiple orders.
- Each added order opens a configuration screen which internal information of the order can be set. Also it is possible to add items to the order.
- Each added item opens a configuration screen that allows user to set internal informations.

To sum up, the flow is Project -> Order -> Item, where "A -> B" means A contains 0, 1 or more Bs.

This project is being developed using WPF with Entity Framework to manage the database access. I am binding entities from Entity database mapping directly into the screens. This way we have some "advantages" with WPF, as not null fields are painted red, for example. Moreover, the code is much simpler. The entities are only updated (or added) to the database when the project is saved. Therefore, items can be edited, then orders can be edited and they are only saved when the project is saved, since they are dependent of the project ID to be saved.

However, using mapped entities directly has a huge problem: let's say the user edits an Item inside an Order. Then, he edits it again, but this time, instead of pressing "OK", the user presses "Cancel". The changes must be reverted. However, the previous state was lost, since it was not updated in the database and were changed because of WPF binding.

What is the best approach to prevent this problem? I don't know if creating clones work well in Entity Framework. And creating variables that only transfer their values to the object when the confirm command is clicked would be against the MVVM pattern, and would make me lose the "advantages" I have already talked about.

Please help me!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just call SaveChanges on your context when the user clicks OK?  This would persist the changes from the first edit, so that the values come back after the user cancels the 2nd edit.

Comment: EF keeps track of old and new values in the `ObjectStateManager`. You can access these like so:http://stackoverflow.com/a/11250496/861716. Likewise you can use these values to overwrite new values with old ones when the user cancels his edit.

Comment: Many times all those "advantages" provided by different APIs are only for simple scenarios. When it comes to a real project with its complexities you must make your hands dirty and start coding instead of hoping that miracle will happen. Your requirement goes directly against binding live entities to your UI because you want to keep unsaved changes intact if user decides to cancel his current editing.